# How to check if page property exists in OctoberCMS layout template

Tags: twig, octobercms

In layout, checking page property with `is defined` produces an error like "Call to undefined method October\Rain\Halcyon\Builder::meta_description()", when page does not define the property.
I expect the test to be false instead of throwing an exception.

I have layout like below checking `if this.page.meta_description is defined`.

```
description = "Default layout"

==
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>{{ this.page.title }}</title>
    {% if this.page.meta_description is defined and this.page.meta_description is not empty %}
          <meta name="description" content="{{ this.page.meta_description }}">
    {% endif %}
    </head>
  <body>
  ...
  </body>
</html>
```

If the page using this layout defines `meta_description` property, it renders fine.
However, if the page does not define it, `this.page.meta_description is defined` part throws exception.

What is the proper way to check if a page property is defined or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a slightly better solution than [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53223032/1646699).

Use `Page.__isset()` method to check if a property is defined.

```
{% if this.page.__isset('meta_description') and this.page.meta_description is not empty %}
  <meta name="description" content="{{ this.page.meta_description }}">
{% endif %}
```

The reason why I think this is a bit better is that this can be used with ViewBag component as well.

I encountered the same problem using `is defined` with ViewBag property. However, array access solution didn't work with ViewBag.
To avoid confusion, I would use `__isset()` method for both Page objects and ViewBag component.

Note: If you are using ViewBag in layout, you should also check if viewBag exists because not all pages instantiate ViewBag component.

```
{% if viewBag is defined and viewBag.__isset('canonical_url') and viewBag.canonical_url is not empty %}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just found a way to solve this situation by accessing the property by associative array syntax.

```
{% if this.page['meta_description'] is defined and this.page['meta_description'] is not empty %}
  <meta name="description" content="{{ this.page.meta_description }}">
{% endif %}
```

This works as I expected, but, I'm not sure if this is the best solution.

Comment: yes its correct and standard solution no need to worry.